# Running erlang shell as a daemon/service

Tags: bash, erlang, daemon

I have an Erlang program that runs in Erlang shell, obviously, and I want to monitor it.

This is what I want:

- When the machine starts the Erlang shell should start up with it, and the program that runs in the shell too.
- If the Erlang shell crashes for some reason it should get restarted.
- You should be able to manually start/stop/restart the Erlang shell.

Example:

```
/etc/init.d/foobar start
/etc/init.d/foobar stop
/etc/init.d/foobar restart
```

I haven't started with the whole "restart itself if crash" thing yet, got stuck with the easy thing, or is it easy?

What I have done is this:

Taken the skeleton code from /etc/init.d/skeleton and replaced the PATH, DESC, NAME etc etc... This works, I can do:

```
/etc/init.d/foobar start
```

However, I cant stop it... The thing is that I start the Erlang shell with "erl" which is a script that does some fancy things that I dont understand. One thing it does is, it creates a very long and complex process name. It's not just "erl" it's like:

/usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.7.4/bin/beam.smp -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /home/xxx -- .... and some more.

Is there a better way to do this?

OS: Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Did you see rebar? https://bitbucket.org/basho/rebar/wiki/Home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to creating a target release, a standard Erlang production environment as recommended by @Martin, you need the following:

- To allow for automatic restart of a crashed node, you should use [the heart functionality](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/heart.html).
- To stop a running Erlang node, you could start up a temporary Erlang node, connect to the running node and issue a stop command:

  ```
  erl -noshell -sname temp_control \
      -eval "rpc:call(mynode@myhost, init, stop, [])" \
      -s init stop
  ```

  - `noshell` disables input and shell output
  - `sname` sets the name for the temporary node
  - `eval` let's you execute any valid Erlang expression

    - `rpc:call(Node, M, F, A)` will call `M:F(A)` on the node specified (`A` is  list of arguments that will be passed to the function as real arguments)
  - `s M F` runs the function `M:F()`

  (`eval` and `s` are run in sequence)

Comment: When I do this I get:
** Connection attempt from disallowed node temp_control@ubuntu **
I haven't figured out how to create a target system yet though... I dont erlang well enough to understand it :(

Comment: Nvm i solved that, they needed to be started with the same cookie :)

Comment: Yeah, creating target systems is notoriously hard and complicated. Please check out Martin's answer (with my comment) for some basic primers on that topic.

Comment: The thing is that it's not me who have written the erlang code, I was just asked to create a script for it. But i have another question about erlang:

I create a temp node which does a rpc to the main node, the function returns a tuple which I want to print out.

The tuple looks like this: {ok,["1234"]}, but when I try to print it using io:write it looks like this: {ok,[[49,50,51,52]]}. Why is this? I just want to print what the rpc call returns? And I want to do it in the command line like so:

erl -noshell -sname temp -setcookie uep1 -eval 'io:write(rpc:call(A,B,C)' -s init stop

Comment: You're better off creating separate questions if you have any additional problems.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is create a target-system. The documentation for doing so is here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/system_principles/create_target.html
However, it is a bit complicated at first, until you get the basic concepts.

Roughly speaking, you do the following:

1. Create an empty node. That is, the 'bin, erts and releases' directories (with updated scripts in bin).
2. Create a release via release_tools as described in the dox.
3. Unpack the release on the empty node, set the release/start_erl.data to point to the new release and erts versions.

This can then be managed as a service with restarts/monitors and whatever you like to add.

Comment: More good resources: [How to Create an Erlang First Target System](http://streamhacker.com/2009/07/02/how-to-create-an-erlang-first-target-system/) and [Erlang/OTP releases: rebar, release_handler, .appup, etc](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlangotp-releases-rebar-release_handler-appup-etc)

Comment: These days, I'd look into using relx - it simplifies it a great deal: https://github.com/erlware/relx

Answer (score 2):

The recently released erld project is an excellent way of truly daemonising an Erlang application.  It provides support for all things a daemon should do, namely:

- Can be started/stopped from an init script
- On startup, control does not return to the console until the program has successfully started (or failed to do so).
- Startup diagnostic information can be printed to the console to indicate progress, but output ceases once the daemon is running.
- On returning to the console, the return code indicates success (0) or failure (some other number).
- Log rotation can be triggered by sending a SIGHUP

See their github page here:  https://github.com/ShoreTel-Inc/erld